# Sentiment Analysis in Python - TextBlob

Tags: python, pandas, analysis, textblob

I am still new to python and learning and one of my courses expects me to use TextBlob and Pandas for sentiment analysis on cvs file. What I did so far I will attach here:

```
Import csv
from textblob import TextBlob
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('Movie_reviews.csv', delimiter='\t', header=None)

Movie_review_texts = df[2]
Movie_review_texts

for intex, review_text in enumerate (Movie_review_texts):
    blob = TextBlob(review_text)
    print('Analysing review\t', review_text)
    for sentence in blob.sentences: 
        print('--------SENTIMENT OF SENTENCE--------')
        print(sentence, '\t', sentence.sentiment.polarity)
        print('-------END-------')
```

however what I need to do now is I need to aggregate the sentiment scores of the constituent sentences and then convert the aggregate score into a boolean value. Which I am really really struggling, I am ready to give up at this point!

Comment: Can you explain a bit `aggregate the sentiment scores of the constituent` ?

Comment: So basically this code gives me a values for every sentence on its own while one review is build form more than one sentences. So what I need to do is give an aggregated value for each review instead of every sentence separate.

Answer (score 0):

This is so far so good. This is one my work and it will help you to perform what you are looking for.

```
from vaderSentiment.vaderSentiment import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer
import time
analyzer = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()

pos_count = 0
pos_correct = 0

with open("D:/Corona_Vac/pythonprogramnet/Positive BOW.txt","r") as f:
    for line in f.read().split('\n'):
        vs = analyzer.polarity_scores(line)
        if not vs['neg'] > 0.1:
            if vs['pos']-vs['neg'] > 0:
                pos_correct += 1
            pos_count +=1


neg_count = 0
neg_correct = 0

with open("D:/Corona_Vac/pythonprogramnet/Positive BOW.txt","r") as f:
    for line in f.read().split('\n'):
        vs = analyzer.polarity_scores(line)
        if not vs['pos'] > 0.1:
            if vs['pos']-vs['neg'] <= 0:
                neg_correct += 1
            neg_count +=1

print("Positive accuracy = {}% via {} samples".format(pos_correct/pos_count*100.0, pos_count))
print("Negative accuracy = {}% via {} samples".format(neg_correct/neg_count*100.0, neg_count))
```

Hope you may find the way. Thanks.